# For any given set of 13 distinct real numbers, prove we can always find two numbers $x$ and $y$ that $0<\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\leq 2-\sqrt{3}$.

Tags: combinatorics

For any given set of 13 distinct real numbers, prove we can always find two numbers x and y that $0<\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}\leq 2-\sqrt{3}$.

I knew we can always make $0<\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$ happen. Since x and y are distinct, we can just switch the order of x and y to change the sign of $\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}$, but what should I do for the right hand side?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426012/given-any-seven-real-numbers-prove-that-0-le-fracx-y1xy-le-frac1-s  also http://www.math.ust.hk/excalibur/v1_n1.pdf

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put $x = \tan(u)$ and $y = \tan(v)$ for some $u, v$ considered modulo $\pi$ (since $\tan$ has period $\pi$). Then $\frac{x-y}{1+xy}$ is $\tan(u-v)$.

So the key is to recognize that two of the angles must be within $\pi/12$ of each other. This is by a pigeonhole principle where we are trying to slot 13 numbers into 12 sectors given by $[0, \pi/12]$, $[\pi/12, 2\pi/12]$, etc.

Comment: Oops, I see you rendered my answer useless. Ah we'll. :p

Comment: @DavidH I feel your pain. MSE is very annoying sometimes, because you always have a bunch of people rushing in to say the same darned thing at the OP! :-)

Comment: Can you explain "for some $u, v$ considered modulo $π$? Does this mean that all numbers are in a range with length $π$? (because the 13 numbers are randomly chosen!).

Comment: @PradeepSuny Just consider $u = \arctan x$, so that $-\frac{\pi}{2} < u < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Notice that it's the $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{13}$ that are randomly chosen.

Answer (score 12):

*Hints:* $\tan(\alpha-\beta) = \dfrac{\tan\alpha - \tan\beta}{1+\tan\alpha \tan\beta}$ and $\tan\dfrac{\pi}{12} = 2-\sqrt{3}$.