# Show that given seven real numbers, it is always possible take two of them, such that $\left\vert\frac{a-b}{1+ab}\right\vert<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

> Show that given seven real numbers, it is always possible take two of them, such that $$\left\vert\frac{a-b}{1+ab}\right\vert<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

The "Pigeonhole principle" states that if $n$ items are put into $m$ containers, with $n > m$, then at least one container must contain more than one item, but how I an define my "container" such that meets the condition of the problem?

Comment: Hint: for each $a_i$ of your seven numbers define $\alpha_i\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ such that $\tan\alpha_i=a_i$.

Comment: Ok, then I take seven real number of the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. And take $\tan(\alpha_{i})=a_{i}$ we have $$\vert\tan(\alpha_{i}-\alpha_{j})\vert=\vert\frac{\tan(\alpha_{i})-\tan(\alpha_{j})}{1-\tan(\alpha_{i})\tan(\alpha_{j})}\vert$$ Then, I can prove that $\vert \tan(x-y)\vert<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$??

Comment: You have 7 numbers in interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. This suggests you should divide this interval into 6 parts (a.k.a. "containers").

Comment: thanks you so much @wokowu !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531468/for-any-given-set-of-13-distinct-real-numbers-prove-we-can-always-find-two-numb , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693689/pigeon-hole-principle-cases

Answer (score 1):

(using  the idea of @Wojowu:)

HINT:
write $a_i = \tan \alpha_i$ with $\alpha_i = \arctan(a_i) \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$. Say 
$$a_1 \le a_2 \le \cdots \le a_7$$
and so 
$$-\frac{\pi}{2} < \alpha_1 \le \alpha_2 \le \cdots \le \alpha_7 < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

We have 
$$ (\alpha_2 -\alpha_1) + ( \alpha_3 - \alpha_2) + \cdots + (\alpha_7 - \alpha_6) = \alpha_7 - \alpha_1 < \frac{\pi}{2} - (-\frac{\pi}{2}) < \pi$$
so at least one of the numbers $\alpha_{i+1} - \alpha_i$ is $< \frac{\pi}{6}$ (the sum had six terms). For that difference we have
$$0 \le \alpha_{i+1} - \alpha_i < \frac{\pi}{6}$$
so $\tan ( \alpha_{i+1} - \alpha_i ) \in ( 0, \tan \frac{\pi}{6})$

Use now the formula for the tangent of the difference and the value  $\tan \frac{\pi}{6}$

$\bf{Added:}$ Since OP mentioned the pigeon-hole principle, let's give a solution using it. Consider the partition of the interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ into $6$ parts:
$$\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right] = \bigsqcup_{k=0}^5 \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+ k\frac{\pi}{6}, -\frac{\pi}{2}+ (k+1)\frac{\pi}{6}\right] $$
At least two of the number $\alpha_i$ ( there are $7$ of them) will be in the same part, so their difference will be $\ge 0$ and $< \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $x_1\leq x_2\leq x_3\leq x_4\leq x_5\leq x_6\leq x_7$ and set $\theta_i = \arctan(x_i)$.
We have $\theta_1\leq\theta_2\leq\theta_3\leq\theta_4\leq\theta_5\leq\theta_6\leq\theta_7$ and for any $i\in[1,7]$, $\theta_i$ is an element of the open interval $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ having length $\pi$. It follows that the distance between the closest $\theta$s, say $\theta_j$ and $\theta_{j+1}$, is $<\frac{\pi}{6}$ and:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\tan\frac{\pi}{6}>\tan\left(\theta_{j+1}-\theta_j\right) = \frac{x_{j+1}-x_j}{1+x_j x_{j+1}}.$$