# Real numbers inequality

Tags: combinatorics

> Consider 9 random and distinct real numbers. Prove that there exist at least 2 of them, $m$ and $n$, for which $0 < \frac{m-n}{1+mn} < \sqrt{2}-1$.

Any ideas? I really don't know where to start from!

The friend who challenged me with this problem claims that it can be solved by using pigeonhole principle, but I have no idea how!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For any given set of 13 distinct real numbers, prove we can always find two numbers $x$ and $y$ that $0<\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\leq 2-\sqrt{3}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531468/for-any-given-set-of-13-distinct-real-numbers-prove-we-can-always-find-two-numb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Given 9 random and distinct real numbers in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ whose size is $\pi$, by the [pigeonhole principle](http://Pigeonhole%20principle) there are at least two of them, say $x$ and $y$, such that
$$0<x-y<\pi/8.$$
Note that $\arctan(\sqrt{2}-1)=\pi/8$.

Answer (score 3):

Another hint:

That formula of $\frac{m-n}{1+mn}$ resembles $\tan(x-y)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you! Solution was really simple but didn't even cross my mind :)