# Prove that between any nine real numbers there are two numbers a, b with the property

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Prove that between any nine real numbers there are two numbers $a, b$ with the property:

$0$ < $\frac{a-b}{1+ab}$ < $\sqrt{2} - 1$

Can someone give me a hint on how to start this problem, please? I don't have any clues. Thank you!

Comment: As 2 square root is 1.414... then minus 1= 0.414..., then you can say that a and b have to a bit larger numbers (so the denominator can be larger so the fraction can be smaller). Does that help? @Henry Bena

Comment: Not really, my teacher wouldn't accept this type of proof, but thank you anyway! @102152111

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For any given set of 13 distinct real numbers, prove we can always find two numbers $x$ and $y$ that $0<\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\leq 2-\sqrt{3}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531468/for-any-given-set-of-13-distinct-real-numbers-prove-we-can-always-find-two-numb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $x,y\in\Bbb R$, $\displaystyle\tan(x-y)=\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(y)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)}$.