# Among any $9$ real numbers, two satisfy $0 < \frac{x-y}{1+xy} < \sqrt{2} - 1$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, pigeonhole-principle

> Prove that among any nine given real numbers there are two numbers $a, b$ with the property:
> $$0 < \dfrac{x-y}{1+xy} < \sqrt{2} - 1$$

The fraction looks like $\tan(a-b)$, but I don't see if it can help. I don't have any other idea, I'm stuck. I also tried by reducing to absurd, but I didn't reach far. Could someone give me a clue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that between any nine real numbers there are two numbers a, b with the property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3880153/prove-that-between-any-nine-real-numbers-there-are-two-numbers-a-b-with-the-pro)

Comment: @cosmo5 I am pretty sure this link does not answer the OP's question, since the only answer just states something the OP included in his question.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried with tan(x-y) (or tan(a-b)) how I wrote it, but I couldn't reacch to any result. Could it be related to Cantor set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For any given set of 13 distinct real numbers, prove we can always find two numbers $x$ and $y$ that $0<\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\leq 2-\sqrt{3}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531468/for-any-given-set-of-13-distinct-real-numbers-prove-we-can-always-find-two-numb)

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outline: let the nine real numbers be $r_1,\dots,r_9$. Define $a_1=\arctan r_1, \dots, a_9=\arctan r_9$. Prove that there exist $1\le i<j\le 9$ satisfying $|a_i-a_j| < \frac\pi8$ (hint: pigeonhole principle). Then consider $\tan(a_i-a_j)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

Divide the half-plane formed by first and fourth quadrants into eight regions by drawing lines emanating from origin at equal angles.

Now argue that some two of given nine numbers must lie in same region. From this you can conclude the given inequality.